# php return multiple variables from other page

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a table with links  that return a 'mf_id' value and its corresponding 'Manufacturer' value. I can do one at a time, but when I try to combine the two, problems begin to crop up. Here's what I have so far:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href=\"list.php?mf_id&&Manufacturer=" . $row['mf_id'&&'Manufacturer'] . "\">" . $row['Manufacturer'] . "</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

and the other page:

```
    $numb = $_GET['mf_id'];
$name = $_GET['Manufacturer'];
echo "<h1>$name</h1>";
$result=mysql_query("select * from Products where mf_id=$numb");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: You never pass `Manufacturer` through your querystring. Also, you should probably `urlencode()` your querystring values before writing to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only passing mf_id into the page, you are not passing Manufacturer.

Edit (as you've changed your code)

Change:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"list.php?mf_id&&Manufacturer=" . $row['mf_id'&&'Manufacturer'] . "\">" . $row['Manufacturer'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

To:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"list.php?mf_id=".$row['mf_id']."&Manufacturer=" . $row['Manufacturer'] . "\">" . $row['Manufacturer'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: As a guy new to web design, I must ask, how would I pass Manufacturer? I had thought that this little string would do so:

echo "<td><a href=\"list.php?mf_id&&Manufacturer="

Apparently I'm mistaken?

Comment: No, you must build a string like list.php?var1=text1&var2=text2

Comment: @user1582828 As @meagar just informed me, you can store the key/value pairs in an array and pass them through `http_build_query()`. Take a look at my answer for the details.

Answer (score 4):

Because you never pass `Manufacturer` through your querystring, the second page doesn't have access to it via `GET`. Also, for validity purposes, your querystring values should be passed through `urlencode()`.

This line:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"list.php?mf_id=" . $row['mf_id'] . "\">" . $row['Manufacturer'] . "</a></td>";
```

Should be:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"list.php?mf_id=" . urlencode($row['mf_id']) . "&Manufacturer=" . urlencode($row['Manufacturer']) . "'\">" . $row['Manufacturer'] . "</a></td>";
```

**Please Note:** It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

**UPDATE:**

Per meagar's advice I learned about `http_build_query()`. This is definitely the way to go when writing querystrings to URLs:

```
$data = array('mf_id' => $row['mf_id'], 'Manufacturer' => $row['Manufacturer']);
echo "<td><a href='list.php?" . http_build_query($data) . "'>" . $row['Manufacturer'] . "</a></td>";
```

Comment: PHP is a language built for the web. It has functions to handle building and accessing query strings. You shouldn't be writing your own.

Comment: @meagar, who's writing their own? `urlencode()` is a PHP function.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make any sense at all: `$row['mf_id'&&'Manufacturer']`. That is not how you access two elements of an array. You're combining two strings with `&&`, yielding boolean `true`, and attempting to access `$row[true]`. You can't access an array that way.

If you want to use both items, you need to access them individually:

```
$row['mf_id'] . $row['Manufacturer']
```

If you want to build a query string containing these two values, you should use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) which will take care of URL-encoding your data:

```
$query = http_build_query(array('mf_id' => $row['mf_id'], 'manufacturer' => $row['Manufacturer']));

echo '<td><a href="list.php?' . $query . '">' . $row['Manufacturer'] . '</a></td>';
```

Note that, if you actually just select the fields you need, you don't have to explicitly specify them in the arguments to `http_build_query`. If your `$row` already contains only `mf_id` and `manufacturer`, it would be enough to use

```
$query = http_build_query($row);
```